# Length of Array Differs In Internet Explorer With Trailing Comma

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer

I'm currently working with some data using Javascript that is in the form of an array.  The array may contain an empty entry at the end, such as `[1,2,]`.  In Google Chrome and Firefox, the length of that example would be 2; however, in IE, the length is 3.

In short: Internet Explorer is giving a different length for an array in Javascript than Google Chrome and Firefox.  Is there a way to standardize this behavior across all browsers?

Code:

```
var a = [1,];
alert(a.length);
```

EDIT:

A lot of answers are saying not to have a trailing comma, however, the data is given to me in this way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Browser Quirks - array.Length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29053/javascript-browser-quirks-array-length)

Comment: @mplungjan: Definitely not a duplicate since I'm not just saying: "O look! A quirk!" I'm asking for a cross browser way to standardize the length.

Comment: Which is given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29053/javascript-browser-quirks-array-length/29062#29062) - it also says "possible" ;)

Comment: See also [IE9 JavaScript array initialization bug](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6196641/357774)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[NEVER have trailing commas in IE. Period.](http://www.google.com/search?q=trailing%20comma%20ie)

[That goes for ARRAYs too](http://www.google.com/search?q=trailing%20comma%20ie%20Array)

[Javascript Browser Quirks - array.Length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29053/javascript-browser-quirks-array-length)

To handle your edit this works (tested in in IE8):

`if (a[a.length-1]==null) a.length--; // or a.pop()`

For a safer test, please look at the other suggestion on this page: [Length of Array Differs In Internet Explorer With Trailing Comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541163/javascript-length-of-array-in-internet-explorer/6541189#6541189) - [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Fhr69/)

By the way, never heard the words [elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma#Elision) or [elided](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elided) before - learn something new here every day

Comment: I've only heard of that with objects, not with Arrays.

Comment: I don't understand why this has plus 3 votes.  The first five links lead to OBJECTS, not arrays.

Comment: Because it does not matter where you have trailing commas, IE will puke as you see. No need to only think about this when it is {} type object and the very first entry in the search DOES have comments about the array too. But just in case I will add the search

Comment: Thanks for the second search, it helped me re-find my question: http://notes.susam.in/2010/06/js-array-length-and-trailing-comma.html

Comment: Yes, that would be the _ideal_ solution.

Comment: @Ivan - you realise that this solution will remove any trailing member whose value is *undefined* or *null*?

Comment: @mplungjan - if you change the test to `a.hasOwnProperty(a.length - 1)`, you'll have a much better answer. Still not as good as mine though. ;-p

Comment: @Rob Great - I voted your answer up. When will my suggestion fail?

Comment: @mplungjan - it will "fail" where the trailing members have been assigned a value of *null* or *undefined* or are *undefined*. An elision doesn't add a property value at all, so it should be a *hasOwnProperty* test (i.e. to see if the property exists, not whether it has a value) it's what *Array.prototype.filter* does.

Comment: @RobG thanks. @Ivan I have updated my answer with a demo of Rob's code. Perhaps worth taking a look at the prototype method used

Answer (score 9):

No. IE incorrectly interprets a single trailing comma as an elision and adds one to the length when it shouldn't (ECMA-262 sect. 11.1.4).

#### Edit

To clear up the confusion here, IE treats a single trailing comma in an array literal (incorrectly) as an elision, which means it increments array's length property **but does not create a property**. In other words, given:

```
var a = [0,1,];
```

In IE, a.length is 3, but there is no property a[2]. So if an appropriate solution is to remove only **elided** members from the end of an array (which is likely the best solution if they are an issue), then:

```
function tidyTrailingElisions(array) {
  var i = array.length;
  while (!array.hasOwnProperty(--i)) {}
  array.length = ++i;
  return array;
}
```

will remove **only** elided members from the end of the array (that is, properties that don't exist), it will not remove them elsewhere, nor will it waste time iterating over the entire array (which can result in elided members being added as undefined). To add to Array.prototype:

```
Array.prototype.tidyTrailingElisions = function() {
  var i = this.length;
  while ( !this.hasOwnProperty(--i)) {}
  this.length = ++i;
  return this;
};
```

Note that this is how *Array.prorotype.filter* works, it doesn't iterate over elided members (it uses a *hasOwnProperty* test and removes any elided mebers as part of filtering the array).

Answer (score 4):

Try removing empty elements:

```
a = a.filter(function(){return true});
```

Then it should work the same way in IE and other browsers.

**Update**: if the JS version is lower than 1.6, try this:

```
Array.prototype.clean = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (this[i] == undefined) {
      this.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    }
  }
  return this;
};


a.clean()
```

Comment: [JS 1.6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) so IE9+

Comment: Thanks for actually answering my question: "Is there a way to standardize this behavior across all browsers?"

Comment: Andy: Would that not be cleverer to clean from the end and stop when an element was found?

Comment: That may have undesired results, it will remove any array index that has not been created as a property anywhere in the array, so: `[,1,,2].filter(function(){return true}).length` is 2.

Comment: I do not believe that [,1,,2] is treated differently by any browser, ONLY [.......,] is. Waste of CPU to clean from the beginning

Comment: @mplungian - precisely. The suggested answer will remove elided members everywhere, not just at the end. Also, the suggested *clean* function is not an alternative to *filter* as it doesn't conform to what *filter* actually does.

Comment: While this is a great solution, I think mplungjan's solution is a lot simpler to implement since this method would require adding a chunk of code for `.clean()`.