# javascript internet explorer array issues

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, yui3

I know that Internet Explorer <9 has issues with Javascript arrays.  I've tried [using](http://code.google.com/p/ddr-ecma5/) [stopgaps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6541169/2004825) but I can't for the life of me get this figured out.

Basically, I have this code (pared way down):

```
YUI.add('query-params', function (Y) {
  Y.QueryParams = {
  /**
  Parses our query string and returns an object containing the k/v pairs passed
  in rules

  @method parse
  @param {String} query string to parse
  @param {RegExp} regex rules to compare our query string against
  @return {Object} returns an object containing the k/v pairs that match
  */
  parse: function (qs, rules, params) {
    qs = qs.replace('?', ''); // remove ? from query string
    qs = qs.replace(/\+/g, ' ');
    var matches = rules.exec(qs);
    var defined_matches = Y.Array.filter(matches, function(m) {
      return ((typeof m != 'undefined') || ( m == true ));
    });

// rest of script omitted
```

And it is initialized as such:

```
  <script>
  YUI({
    modules: {
      'query-params': {
        fullpath: './parse_search_terms.js'
      }
    },
    onFailure: function (error) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
  }).use('node', 'console', 'query-params', function (Y) {
    var params = Y.QueryParams.parse(window.location.search, /(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\w+)|(\w+)\s(\w+)/ig, ["firstName", "lastName", "state"]);
    var url = "url_to_send_to?firstName=" + params.firstName + "&lastName=" + params.lastName + "&state=" + params.state;

    var iframe = Y.Node.create('<iframe></iframe>').setAttrs({
      src: url,
      frameBorder: 'no',
      height: 300,
      width: 800,
      scrolling: 'no'
});
    Y.one('#iframe').appendChild(iframe);
});
```

What I get in IE, Firefox and Chrome when I pass a query string like "q=john+smith+ca" and JSON.stringify the matches variable is this:

```
john smith ca,john,smith,ca,,
```

Firefox and Chrome do the right thing when I call Y.Array.filter on the array:

```
defined ["john","smith","ca"]
```

Internet Explorer 8 however:

```
defined ["john","smith","ca","",""]
```

So for some reason IE isn't filtering my array properly.  I've tried all the aforementioned array shims and stopgaps but nothing seems to work.  I would think that this would be pretty cross browser efficient since I'm using YUI3, but I'm stumped.

Anyone have any ideas? Help much appreciated.

Comment: The filter function doesn't make a lot of sense. If `m == true` is true, then `typeof m` cannot be "undefined".

Comment: Well, nothing changes if I use var defined_matches = Y.Array.filter(matches, function(m) {
        return typeof m != 'undefined';
      });

Comment: OK, well it was just an observation.

Comment: no worries, I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that IE drops into "quirks mode" if the doctype isn't set. adding "" to the top of the page fixed everything.