# Why do Array literals with commas but no elements not have a length of 0?

Tags: javascript

I was just fiddling with some JS and found something I thought would not happen.

```
var arr = [,];
arr.length // 1
arr[0] // undefined
```

Moreover, `[,,]` has a length of 2.  Shouldn't these arrays have lengths of 0?  I thought commas were only used to separate elements in an array, so why does it appear that commas are counted as elements in these particular arrays? Does this kind of behavior with arrays have any sort of application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between `[undefined]` and `[,]`?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11808946/1048572)

Comment: …and also related: [Length of Array Differs In Internet Explorer With Trailing Comma](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6541163/1048572)

Comment: @Gothdo: Because I wasn't sure whether it's an exact duplicate ("explain the difference" vs "why do they have a length"), because that is not explained that well, because I've answered the duplicate, because the proposed duplicate is closed as a duplicate itself… Too much doubt to hammer it instantly. Given that quite a lot of people seem to agree, I'll do now.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In an array literal, a comma at the end is ignored, but all the other commas delimit elements. If you omit the value of an element, it defaults to `undefined`, but the element is still there. So

```
[,]
```

is equivalent to

```
[undefined,]
```

which is equivalent to

```
[undefined]
```

This has 1 element whose value is `undefined`.

Similarly

```
[,,] = [undefined, undefined, ] = [undefined, undefined]
```

which has 2 elements.

The default element behavior is more useful when you want to omit elements in the middle of an array.

```
[1, 2, 3, , , 6, 7, 8]
```

Actually, there's a small difference between the two ways of creating undefined elements. In Javascript, an array is actually an object that has a `length` property and properties whose names are the indexes of the array elements. Normally, if an array has `length = N`, the index properties will be all the integers from `0` to `N-1`. But when you omit an element in the array literal, no property is created for that index.

For most purposes, this missing property is not significant, because accessing a nonexistent property of an object returns `undefined`, just as if you have a property whose value is `undefined`. You can only detect these missing properties by using a method like `hasOwnProperty` or calling `Object.keys`. The Javascript console uses something like this to display gaps in the array differently from explicit `undefined` elements.

So

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames([1, 2, 3]) => ["0", "1", "2", "length"]
Object.getOwnPropertyNames([1, , 3, 4]) => ["0", "2", "3", "length"]
Object.getOwnPropertyNames([, , , , ]) => ["length"]
```

The reason for ignoring the last comma is so you can write:

```
[ 
    "foo",
    "bar",
    "baz",
    "quux",
]
```

This makes editing easier, because you can insert and delete lines without having to special-case the last element.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but the console shows a slight diffence bettwen `[,,]` and `[undefined, undefined]`. That being `[,,] = [undefined × 2]`. What is the reasoning for that, is it just my browser?

Comment: That's how the console displays sparse arrays.

Comment: So is it safe to assume that if there is nothing before a comma, it defaults to `undefined,`?

Comment: Actually, there is a difference. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 8):

That's called elision. It creates a "hole" in the array (a sparse array). There are probably applications I don't know about and have forgotten about, the only one I can think of right now is the one I show here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29629588/1034448.

```js
[,...Array(10)].map((x, i) => { /* range of `i` is 1 - 10 */ })
```

`[,,]` is *not* equivalent to `[undefined, undefined,]`. There is a big difference: iteration methods will not include elements at the elided indexes. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/mcdcn0h0/):

```js
var enumerated = [];

function callback (x, i) {
  enumerated.push(i);
}

[,,].forEach(callback);
console.log(enumerated); // logs []

[undefined, undefined,].forEach(callback);
console.log(enumerated); // logs [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Array_literals

The trailing comma is ignored in newer browsers.

Comment: based on your answer alone, wouldn't `[,]` and `[]` be identical?

Comment: @eis no, the [,]=[undefined,]=[undefined]. The other one is [].

Comment: I know, but I don't see you telling that in your answer.